# Ant excludesfile compiling java files

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors

I have a fairly simple ant script that is running my dependencies I'm importing into the class I need to compile using Ant.  The excludes doesn't seem to be right.

```
 <property name="dir.src" location="src"/>
 <property name="dir.org" location="src\org"/> 
 <target name="compile" description="compile the source">
    <mkdir dir="build"/> 

    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac listfiles="true" includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${dir.src}" classpath="${dir.src}" destdir="${build} debug="on" >
        <include name="src/TaskJob.java" />
        <exclude name="${dir.org}" /> 
    </javac>
</target>
```

The compile runs 1900 java files with

```
Directory----
---------build.xml
---------+src
-------------+org
-------------TaskJob.java
---------.git
```

I'm also trying

```
<dirset id="dirset" dir="${dir.src}">
     <include name="src/**.java"/>
     <exclude name="src/org/**"/>
</dirset>
```

and then using a filename:

```
<javac exclude="dirset" srcdir="${dir.src} destdir="classes" debug="on" >
     <filename name="${dir.src}\TaskJob.java"/>
</javac>
```

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: Information in the comments as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has the following...

```
<property name="dir.src" location="src"/>
<property name="dir.org" location="src\org"/>
```

...and the following...

```
<javac ... srcdir="${dir.src}" ...>
    <include name="src/TaskJob.java" />
    <exclude name="${dir.org}" />
</javac>
```

Replacing the properties with their actual values would give the following...

```
<javac ... srcdir="src" ...>
    <include name="src/TaskJob.java" />
    <exclude name="src\org" />
</javac>
```

`src` appears in both `srcdir` and `<include>`. The `<include>` would match the following TaskJob.java if it existed in your scenario...

```
Directory----
---------build.xml
---------src
-------------src
-----------------org
-------------TaskJob.java
```

Notice how there is a `src` subdirectory under another `src` directory.

So, what you want is the following...

```
<javac ... srcdir="src" ...>
    <include name="TaskJob.java" />
</javac>
```

There is no need for an `<exclude>` element. Just the `<include>` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude all java files under `org` directory.

```
<javac listfiles="true" includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${dir.src}" classpath="${dir.src}" destdir="${build} debug="on" >
    <exclude name="org/**" /> 
    <include name="src/TaskJob.java" />
</javac>
```

For more detail and example, you can read the [document of FileSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

Comment: The directory is still being compiled.  I tried with verbose and without not quite seeing why the include alone doesn't handle looking past with seeing I don't have a ton of .java files for the build that I'm asking for.

Comment: I just update answer (`exclude` should move up). Make sure you also clean `build\org` directory.

Comment: Nope that didn't fix it for me. @beckyang

Comment: The `<exclude>` needs the leading `src` directory. So: `<exclude name="src/org/**" />`

Comment: @Chad Nouis, I build the same *DIrectory** as the question mentioned. `<exclude name="org/**"/>` works in my testing. **src** is not required because `<javac srcdir="src">` and **org** is a sub-directory of it. I am wondering why it does not work...